# List record from table by selects MAX value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

i have a table as following:

Account(Acc_number,Acc_balance,branch_code)

Now i want to list all account details in each branch with the highest balance, how should I write the sql statement?

Simply said, i just want to list out all the branches, with the account of having highest balance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column).

You can use analytic functions.

Try this if it works for you:

```
    select branch_code,acc_number,acc_balance from
(
        select distinct acc_number,branch_code,acc_balance, 
        max(acc_balance) over(partition by branch_code order by 1) as MAX 
        from Account
)

    where acc_balance=MAX
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but Your result listed all the accounts, what i want is only listed one highest account in every branch.

Comment: I revised my answer accordingly.